# What does 八 have to do with [八つ当たり]【やつあたり】?

Tags: words, etymology

For the longest time, I had never seen *yatsuatari* written down. I always figured it was written 奴当たり, which I figured would have been derived from 「あの奴に当たる」 or something.

Imagine my surprise when I discovered that it was actually written 八つ当たり! I found myself rather confused by the kanji here. What does 八 "eight" have to do with 八つ当たり "venting one's anger on other people"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it means to vent the anger in the 8 compass directions. I.e. you are so angry that the effects reach every direction around you.

Consider 四方八方. It refers to all sides or everywhere. I think 八つ refers to the 八方 part

Comment: 広辞苑 says: 誰彼の区別なく**八方へ当たり**散らすこと。関係のない人にまで怒り散らすこと。「部下に―する」

Comment: Similar expressions abound, e.g. 八方ふさがり, 八方美人